# Mypy Function "lxml.etree.ElementTree" is not valid as a type but why?

Tags: python, lxml, mypy, typing

I am using Mypy for this function

```
import funcy as fu
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Element, ElementTree

def find_nodes(tree: ElementTree, paths: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[Element]:
    """Yield all non-zero nodes for the given paths in the tree."""
    return fu.remove(fu.isnone, map(tree.find, paths))
```

checking this file with mypy (0.942) and lxml-stubs gives me this strange error:

```
xxx\layout\treeutils.py:9: error: Function "lxml.etree.ElementTree" is not valid as a type
xxx\layout\treeutils.py:9: note: Perhaps you need "Callable[...]" or a callback protocol?
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Strangely, lxml ElementTree (or Element for that matter) is a Function, _ElementTree would be the class, but is protected.

Answer (score 2):

In `lxml-stubs`, `ElementTree` is indeed declared as a function. It returns an object of type `_ElementTree`, which *is* declared as a class. Something similar is happening for `Element` and `_Element`.

Looking into `lxml` itself, it turns out that this is right: `_ElementTree` is [defined](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/53c5a224a4e6f8209a063ebc003cf296c5844b43/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L1871-L1872) as a Cython class, and `ElementTree` is [defined](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/53c5a224a4e6f8209a063ebc003cf296c5844b43/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L3156) as a function. I don't know enough about Cython to say why it's implemented this way.

So this works:

```
from lxml.etree import Element, ElementTree, _Element, _ElementTree

def find_nodes(tree: _ElementTree, paths: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[_Element]:
```

I wouldn't worry too much about the underscore here. A single underscore is merely a convention to indicate protected types, and doesn't have a special meaning to the Python interpreter. If lxml chooses to expose such types as return values in its public API, chances are they're not going anywhere in future versions of lxml. Your choice is to use these types and enjoy some type safety, or resort to `Any` and have no type safety at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
Found already a few bugs.

Answer (score 1):

To suplement Thomas' answer, `etree.ElementTree()` is a factory function that creates `etree._ElementTree` objects. Same for `etree.Element()` vs `etree._Element`. Therefore, the function signature should have been:

```py
def find_nodes(tree: _ElementTree, paths: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[_Element]:
    ...
```

BTW, you are welcome to check out my [release of `types-lxml`](https://github.com/abelcheung/types-lxml) which completely supersedes `lxml-stubs` as the newest release is feature complete. When using `types-lxml` for type checking, you would want to add subscript to `_ElementTree`, which denotes the type of element the tree contains:

```py
def find_nodes(tree: _ElementTree[_Element], paths: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[_Element]:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the new types, will give them a try